# Koin. Cannot inject to fragment with ScopeActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, koin, koin-scope

I'm trying to inject some dependency to both activity and fragment using Koin and I expect it to live as long as activity lives, but it turned out a headache for me.

I managed to create a module that resolves MainRouter, inject it into an activity, but it doesn't work for a fragment.

```
val appModule = module {
    scope<MainActivity> {
        scoped { MainRouter() }
    }
}
```

MainActivity extends ScopeActivity, MyFragment extends ScopeFragment.

in MainActivity `private val router : MainRouter by inject()` works fine, but in MyFragment it throws org.koin.core.error.**NoBeanDefFoundException**: No definition found for class:'com.example.app.MainRouter'. Check your definitions!

Finally I managed to inject, but it doesn't look pretty

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val scopeId = scopeActivity!!.getScopeId()
    scope.linkTo(getKoin().getScope(scopeId))
    mainRouter = get()
    ...
```

I also don't like that `scopeActivity` can't be accessed in the init method. Does this mean that activity scoped dependencies cannot be resolved in fragment using `by inject()`?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your code, you have to declare a `Fragment` instance, just declare it as a `fragment` in your Koin module and use constructor injection. Like below:

```
    val appModule = module {
    single { MyService() }
    fragment { MyFragment(get()) }
}
```

Please refer [link](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/fragment-factory/) for more details.

Comment: Trying to figure it out. I'm creating a fragment with `MyFragment.newInstance()` inside an Adapter createFragment() fun, so the fragment class becomes `class MyFragment(mainRouter: MainRouter? = null)`. How to make router injected? Because passing router as param is not a good idea, MyFragment(get()) would never called after a fragment recreation. And sadly docs only contains info on how to make it with supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction(), not newInstance() way

Comment: Pratik, any help?

Comment: Yes. I can but can you please share code of MainRouter?

Comment: Suppose it's a class with some logic in it. The problem is reproduced with an empty MainRouter class.